# Node.js buffer xor unexpected behavior

Tags: node.js, xor, async.js

Scenario:

- the user uploads a file of X size that is divided in 12 equal chunks; in case the result of the division is not a unsigned int I round it on the upper bound, all chunks will have the same length except the last one
- the 12 chunks are preprocessed and 6 erasure chunks (4 locals and 2 globals) are created with the purpose of restoring the file; I chose this approach to reduce the disk size needed and to optimize the recovery and add some fault tolerance

**Working scenario code**

```
function erasureChunkCreate(chunks,callback) {
let erasureChunks = {};
let locale = undefined;
let global = undefined;
erasureChunks = {'local': {}, 'global': {}};
async.eachSeries(chunks, (item, callback_times) => {
    if (locale === undefined)
        locale = item.chunk.slice();
    else
        locale = xor(locale, item.chunk);

    if (item.seq_no % 3 === 2) {
        erasureChunks['local'][Math.ceil(item.seq_no / 3)] = locale;
        if (global === undefined)
            global = locale.slice();
        else
            global = xor(global, locale);
        locale = undefined;
    }
    callback_times(null);
}, (err_times) => {
    if (err_times)
        return callback(err_times, null);
    erasureChunks['global'] = global;
    return callback(null, erasureChunks);
});
```

}

Problem:

- if the globals is placed after the computation of the locale xor I get the next unexpected behavior, different chunk hashes

**Unexpected scenario leading code part**

```
    if (locale === undefined)
        locale = item.chunk.slice();
    else
        locale = xor(locale, item.chunk);

    if (global === undefined)
        global = locale.slice();
    else
        global = xor(global, locale);

    if (item.seq_no % 3 === 2) {
        erasureChunks['local'][Math.ceil(item.seq_no / 3)] = locale;
        locale = undefined;
    }
```

What have I tried:

- debugging and manually checking the buffer and xor results, seeing that the 2 scenarios produce different xor values
- trying to change the logic of the code (leading to working scenario code)

Modules used:

- async
- buffer-xor